# How to set "Unlock login keyring" - off in kubuntu 20?

Tags: kde, keyrings

Where in kubuntu can I set option
"Unlock login keyring" - off for my Chrome and skype?
I searched in these apps and did not find any options...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no version 20.